# The close button on my image modals isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I managed to create an **image gallery with modals**. It turns out to work, however in doing so, it broke the close button and the only way to close the modal is to reload the page.

Here is the code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
var img3 = document.getElementById('myImg3');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

//handle click for myImg2
img2.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

//handle click for myImg3
img3.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg3 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

#myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

#myImg3:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>

<img id="myImg" src="butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" width="300" height="200">

<img id="myImg2" src="thestreetthatgotmislaid.png" alt="The Street That Got Mislaid" width="300" height="200">
```

NOTE: Since I created new element IDs for the images, did it cause the close button to not work or was it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, there is no longer an `img3` element, so your code is failing before it can add the click listener to the `close` span

You should either remove any code that references `img3`, or add that element back in

You can also add the click listeners in a loop, instead of adding each one by ID. This means that you can add / remove images without needing to update the code

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// Loop through each of the images
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }   
};

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg3 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

#myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

#myImg3:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>

<img id="myImg" src="butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" width="300" height="200">

<img id="myImg2" src="thestreetthatgotmislaid.png" alt="The Street That Got Mislaid" width="300" height="200">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked and so if I want to add another image, I just add the img3 element and so on. Thank you :)

Comment: Exactly. If you want to make it even easier to maintain, you could try getting the elements by tag name (`img`), and adding the click listeners in a loop. That way you can add / remove images without needing to update the code :)

Comment: and how do I put the listeners in a loop? (Sorry if this is a stupid question)

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is you declare element img 3 which is not carry any element.Just Remove
img3 and this work fine

Here the Solution

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
         <head>
            //add your css
         </head>
     <body>

       <!-- The Modal -->
           <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                 <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                <div id="caption"></div>
               </div>

          <h2>Image Modal</h2>

           <img id="myImg" src="butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" width="300" height="200">

        <img id="myImg2" src="thestreetthatgotmislaid.png" alt="The Street That Got Mislaid" width="300" height="200">

      <script>
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

         // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
        var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
          var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
          img.onclick = function(){
         modal.style.display = "block";
          modalImg.src = this.src;
         captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

      //handle click for myImg2
         img2.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
          captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
       }

     // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

     window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target == modal) {
             modal.style.display = "none";
       }
    }

   </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```